# Are there any companies providing enterprise support for redis?

Tags: redis, jedis

We have a use case in our organization, for which using redis as in-memory db best fits as solution.But to use it we need to have an enterprise support. I did a lot of search in google but couldn't find one which provides enterprise support.

Pls help if you know any company providing the same.

Comment: I am not aware of companies providing support for redis. But since this questions was tagged with Jedis, I assume you are using jedis? I'm the owner of Jedis, any help you might need, just let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check with companies like [Garantia Data](http://garantiadata.com/) which runs [Redis Cloud](http://redis-cloud.com/), or [RedisToGo](http://redistogo.com) for Enterprise Support options.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try a hosted redis provider http://openredis.com, I'm not sure if they provide enterprise level support.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.gopivotal.com/big-data/redis

Pivotal is the main supporter of the project and the employer of the author.